# Duda con consulta PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Necesito que esta función me valide si una cita ya existe para una trabajadora y a determinada hora:

```php
public function addCita($Next,$Trabajadora,$Cliente,$Concat,$Suma,$Observaciones,$Estado)
    {
        $sql= "SELECT * from cita WHERE Id_Trabajadora= :Trabajadora and Fecha_Hora= :Concat and Id_Estado != 3";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $parameters = array(':Trabajadora' => $Trabajadora,':Concat' => $Concat, ':Estado' => $Estado);
        //echo '[ PDO DEBUG ]: ' . Helper::debugPDO($sql, $parameters);  exit();
        $query->execute($parameters);
        $resultado = $query->fetchAll();

        var_dump($resultado)

        if ($resultado) {
            return false;
            die();
        }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `cita`(`Id_Cita`, `Id_Trabajadora`, `Id_Cliente`, `Fecha_Hora`, `Precio_Total`, `Observaciones`, `Id_Estado`) VALUES (:Next, :Trabajadora, :Cliente, :Concat, :Suma, :Observaciones, :Estado)";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $parameters = array(':Next' => $Next, ':Trabajadora' => $Trabajadora, ':Cliente' => $Cliente, ':Concat' => $Concat, ':Suma' => $Suma, ':Observaciones' => $Observaciones, ':Estado' => $Estado);
        //echo '[ PDO DEBUG ]: ' . Helper::debugPDO($sql, $parameters);  exit();
        $query->execute($parameters);
        }



    }
```

El problema que tengo es que se salta la validación y siempre guarda, cualquier ayuda con este problema se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Y qué tal si validas: `if($resultado != "")` ?, y en vez de `fetchAll()`, pones sólo un `fetch();`

Comment: ¿Qué obtienes con el echo si lo ejecutas? ¿Has probado la consulta en PhpMyAdmin?, ¿el resultado fue el esperado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que no hay coherencia en tu consulta `SELECT`, ya que en el `execute` estás pasando un parámetro `:Estado` que no has indicado en el `prepare`. Imagino que quieres filtrar por el valor que se pasó en la variable `$Estado`. Entonces tienes que agregar ese parámetro, que ahora mismo está escrito a mano con un valor `3`.

Aparte de eso, cuando escribas funciones conviene establecer un control estricto en ellas, de modo que puedas saber fácilmente qué ha ocurrido en tu función. Aquí he implementado una práctica que consiste en recoger la información dentro de un array `$response` con dos claves: `status` y `msg`. Luego, en el resultado de la función puedes verificar `status` y si quieres mostrar el mensaje de lo que ocurrió usas la clave `msg` para mostrar lo que hay en ella.

Otra cosa es que, si la finalidad del `SELECT` es únicamente saber si el registro existe, es mejor hacer una consulta basa en `COUNT` y luego obtener la cantidad de filas, usando `fetchColumn()`. Es más ligero y más seguro que hacer un `fetchAll` con unos datos que al fin y al cabo no vas a usar.

Aplicando todo eso el código quedaría así.

```
<?php
    public function addCita($Next,$Trabajadora,$Cliente,$Concat,$Suma,$Observaciones,$Estado)
    {
        $sql= "SELECT COUNT(*) from cita WHERE Id_Trabajadora= :Trabajadora and Fecha_Hora= :Concat and Id_Estado !=:Estado";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $parameters = array(':Trabajadora' => $Trabajadora,':Concat' => $Concat, ':Estado' => $Estado);
        if ( !$query->execute($parameters) )
        {
            $response=array("status"=>FALSE, "msg"=>"Error en la consulta SELECT");
        }
        else
        {
            if ( $query->fetchColumn()>0 )
            {
                $response=array("status"=>FALSE, "msg"=>"$Trabajadora existe");
            }
            else
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `cita`(`Id_Cita`, `Id_Trabajadora`, `Id_Cliente`, `Fecha_Hora`, `Precio_Total`, `Observaciones`, `Id_Estado`) VALUES (:Next, :Trabajadora, :Cliente, :Concat, :Suma, :Observaciones, :Estado)";
                $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $parameters = array(':Next' => $Next, ':Trabajadora' => $Trabajadora, ':Cliente' => $Cliente, ':Concat' => $Concat, ':Suma' => $Suma, ':Observaciones' => $Observaciones, ':Estado' => $Estado);
                if ( !$query->execute($parameters) )
                {
                    $response=array("status"=>FALSE, "msg"=>"Error en la consulta INSERT");
                }
                else
                {
                    $response=array("status"=>TRUE, "msg"=>"$Trabajadora insertada");
                }
            }
    
        }
    return $response;       
    }
?>
```

##Ejemplo de uso

```
$mData=addCita (....aquí los parámetros...);
if ( $mData["status"] ) 
{
    //Se insertó el registro
    //Puedes mostrar $mData['msg'] si quieres
}
else
{
    echo "Hubo un error: $mData[msg]";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
try {
    //conectarse a la base de datos
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=control_de_clientes; charset=utf8', 'root', '123456');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


//seleccionar datos
$datos = $dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) from cita WHERE Id_Trabajadora= :Trabajadora and Fecha_Hora= :Concat and Id_Estado !=:Estado");
$number_of_rows = $datos->rowCount();



if ($number_of_rows == 1) {
    echo "<h2> cita ya existe</h2>";
} else {
    //insertar la cita
}
```

Comment: `rowCount()` no es una buena opción para este caso, por lo que dice el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php) al respecto: *Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement asociado fue **una sentencia SELECT**, algunas bases de datos **podrían** devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo, **este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables**.* En otras palabras, puede haber contextos en los que `rowCount` no devuelva el total de filas.