# No me funciona el prepare PDO en PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Soy principiante en PHP y estoy tratando de validar el registro de usuarios y comprobar si están en la base de datos. La cuestión es que estoy intentando este código y no me sale. Trabajo en localhost con xampp en ubuntu.

```
 $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario LIMIT 1');
        $statement->execute (array(':usuario'=> $usuario));
        $resultado = $statement->fetch();
```

En cambio si lo pongo así, parece que si funciona.

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios');
        $statement->execute ();
        $resultado = $statement->fetch();
```

Donde esta el error en el primer caso? Cual es la diferencia de hacerlo de una u otra manera? Es correcta la segunda?
El resto de código parece que esta correcto, pues funciona todo correcto hasta llegar aquí.

El código completo hasta que me ha dado el error es el siguiente.

```
<?php session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {

    header('Location: index.php');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $usuario = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['usuario']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

    $errores ='';

    if (empty($usuario) or empty($password) or empty($password2)) {

        $errores .= '<li>Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
    }
    else {

        try {

            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cursophp', 'root', '');

        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {

            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario LIMIT 1');
        $statement->execute (array(':usuario'=>$usuarios));
        $resultado = $statement->fetch();
        var_dump($conexion->errorInfo());

        

        if ($resultado != false) {

            $errores .= '<li>El nombre de usuario ya existe</li>';
        }

      
    }
}

require 'view/registrate_view.php';
```

?>

le hice un var_dump y me salio esto:

Notice: Undefined variable: usuarios in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cursoPHP/practicas/0.3_InicioSesion_RegistroUsuarios/registrate.php on line 33
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } carlos .

Comment: No veo ningún error en las dos formas, que por lo demás son distintas. En la primera hay un criterio y un límite que te traeria un solo registro, en la segunda no hay criterio ni limite y te traería todos los registros. En la parte donde falla pon un `var_dump($conexion->errorInfo());` y dinos qué muestra. Puede ser que el nombre de la columna esté mal escrito, es la única posibilidad de error que se me ocurre. Aunque tampoco explicas de qué modo usas `$resultado`.  No vendría mal un `var_dump($resultado);`para hacer debug de los datos en sí, ya que a veces lo que falla es el uso de los mismos

Comment: Gracias por tu rápida respuesta. El nombre de la base de datos y de la tabla esta bien, añadí el error que me daba y el código completo, pero sigo sin saber cual es la razón de que no se conecte a la bd.

Comment: Pues yo creo que es un error de sintaxis. Una variable la llamas $usuario, y en otro lado la llamas $usuarios, en mayúscula. Probablemente ese sea tu error.

Comment: Si, ese error existe, pero me sigue sin decir que ese usuario que pongo ya existe y me sigue dando el error  array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

Comment: Aparte de lo que te señala @Mimmetico, hay varios errores más en tu código. 1. Si var a usar el dato de la variable `$usuario` solamente como criterio de la consulta no necesitas filtarla, eso lo hace la consulta preparada; 2. Si estás usando `try ... catch` la preparación y ejecución de la consulta debería ir en el `try`, así podrás capturar cualquier error que ocurra en el `catch`. 3. Das demasiadas vueltas a los datos, toda la verificación de si el POST tiene esos datos o no se puede simplificar con ternarios.

Comment: Gracias a los dos por las respuestas. Estoy siguiendo un tutorial para aprender a trabajar con bases de datos desde php y el chico lo escribe así y le funciona. Quiza lo hace así para que sea más fácil la explicación. Ignoro si hay otras maneras de hacer consultas preparadas más sencillas, pero buscare ahora alguna alternativa. Lo curioso es que a él si le funciona y a mi no.  Por cierto, no encuentro como puntuar vuestras respuestas y me gustaría hacerlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparte del error de sintaxis ya señalado, hay varias cosas mejorables en tu código, trato de enumararlas:

1. No queda claro si lo que interesa en este código es una búsqueda de errores ¿? Lo digo porque parece que se intenta recoger todo en una variable `$errores`. Me he permitido cambiar el nombre de esa variable.
2. Se puede simplificar la forma de recoger los datos del POST, usando un ternario. Si esos datos son únicamente para usarlos como criterio de la consulta SQL no hace falta filtrarlos, eso ya lo hace la consulta preparada, no hay que abusar de los filtros, filtrando datos dos veces. En ese mismo sentido, hay dos variables que no se sabe para que son...
3. Si estás usando un bloque `try ... catch` debes poner dentro del `try` todo aquello de lo que puedas capturar error. En ese sentido la preparación y ejecución de la consulta pueden levantar excepciones, por tanto, toda esa lógica debe ir dentro del `try`
4. Faltan algunos `else` que he completado. El código queda en blanco en algunas ramas. Conviene que definas un poco cuál es la intención de este código. Algunos de esos `else` los he completado (por ejemplo cuando el método no sea POST). Pero por ejemplo, el código no hace nada cuando encuentra registros. He puesto un comentario con una interrogante en esa parte.
5. Si aquí se trata sólo de verificar si ese usuario existe, es más propio usar una consulta del tipo `SELECT COUNT(*)` y verificar el total de filas con `fetchColumn()`

Posiblemente se escapen otros pequeños detalles, pero ahí ya tienes varios puntos para optimizar tu código.

Aplicando todo lo dicho, tu código podría escribirse de este modo:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    $msg="";
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $usuario   = !empty($_POST['usuario'])   ? $_POST['usuario']   : NULL;
        #¿Para qué son estas variables?
        $password  = !empty($_POST['password'])  ? $_POST['password']  : NULL;
        $password2 = !empty($_POST['password2']) ? $_POST['password2'] : NULL;
        #Es más lógico en este caso evaluar en positivo
        if ($usuario && $password && $password2) {
          try {
              $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cursophp', 'root', '');
              $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario LIMIT 1');
              $statement->execute (array(':usuario'=>$usuario));
              $resultado = $statement->fetch();
              if ($resultado) {
                  $msg .= '<li>El nombre de usuario ya existe</li>';
              } #¿No hay que mostrar nada si no existe?
          }
          catch (PDOException $e) {
              $msg .= "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
          }  

        } else {
          $msg .= '<li>Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
        }
    } else {
      $msg.= "Método no permitido";
    }

    /*Usar $msg*/

    require 'view/registrate_view.php';
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta y la molestia de arreglar el código. Este archivo junto con otros trata de hacer un registro de usuarios para acceder a ciertas partes de la web. Con este código trato de saber si el usuario ya existe dentro de la base de datos. No seguí con el tutorial porque llevaba 4 horas, de las cuales la ultima me la pase estancado buscando una solución al problema, y estaba ya un poco saturado. La variable $usuario se utiliza para comparar el nombre con la base de datos. La de $password supongo que las ha creado para compararlas entre ellas y que sean iguales.

Comment: Lo de los $errores los recoge por si hay algún dato del formulario de registro que esta mal. A lo de los ternarios no he llegado todavía, no se como funciona, pero si es una buena alternativa, ya lo buscare para aprenderlo. Mañana pruebo el codigo que me has pasado y te digo. Gracias por todo.

Comment: @jbort de nada. El problema de muchos tutoriales es que están desactualizados, o simplemente que no implementan buenas prácticas. Por tu comentario entiendo que se trata de un tutorial en vídeo o algo asi... Quizá yo sea de otra generación, pero nunca jamas he podido aprender a programar viendo tutoriales, sinceramente prefiero leer un tutorial en texto y luego practicar con el código. Otro elemento importante es la documentación (leerla, conocerla, consultarla) y, en el caso concreto de PHP, las notas de contribución (son aportaciones de los usuarios) al final de cada tema.

Comment: Si, es el problema que tenemos a la hora de buscar cursos online, están desactualizados o te encuentras con un problema y no hay manera de solucionarlo. Aunque este curso es del 2018 y en un principio tenia muy buenas referencias.

Comment: Estuve mirando tu código, se entiende mucho mejor y se ve mejor estructurado. El problema no me lo ha solucionado, pues me sigue sin avisar de que el usuario ya existe cuando registro a alguien que ya esta en la base de datos. Me saltare esta parte del tutorial y mirare mejor como hacer estas consultas, tambien revisaré en mi bd que este todo correcto. Gracias de nuevo por tu tiempo.

Comment: @jbort pero ¿qué hace el código actualmente? Hay varios cabos sueltos en tu código, por ejemplo, ¿por qué usas un `<li>`  para las respuestas? En el planteamiento inicial ni siquiera se entendía lo que quería hacer el código, la redirección que hay al principio tampoco se entiende mucho. Mientras más claro seas cuando plantees una pregunta mejor y más clara será la ayuda. Por algo tan simple como usar un `li` que luego no integras bien donde recibes la respuesta de este código podrías no estar viendo la respuesta.

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver. Era un error de sintaxis. En teoria tiene que haber más validaciones del formulario, si hay varios errores hace que se vean como una lista.

Comment: @jbort Correcto. Si la respuesta de este código va integrada en una lista, debes poner `<li>` a todos los `$msg`, aunque es algo un poco extraña esta forma de programar. Por ejemplo, un error no debería ir en la lista, sino ser mostrado de otra forma. Generalmente en este tipo de códigos es mejor ir recogiendo en un array el estado del código por un lado y el contenido a presentar por otro. Así, en el array pondrías una clave `error` y al recibir la respuesta verificas si tiene esa clave para tratar los errores de otro modo, no como `<li>`

Comment: Tal y como esta el codigo, todavía no se ven todos los errores. Pero ya me avisa que el usuario existe, que era donde fallaba. Todo lo demás parece funcionar correctamente. El trabajo trata de hacer un formulario de registro o de acceder a un lugar si ya estas registrado. En otros archivos tengo el contenido y el login, aquí trato de validar el formulario de registro y evitar que se registre dos veces la misma persona. Perdon si no me explico bien.

Comment: En el código de la respuesta yo te puse este comentario `} #¿No hay que mostrar nada si no existe?`  porque en tu código original no quedaba claro qué debía ocurrir en el caso de que el usuario no existiese. Por eso yo cambié la variable `$errores` por `$msg` porque realmente tu código no debe pensarse como algo que va a controlar errores **solamente**. De hecho, cuando esos supuestos errores no ocurren, tu código no devuelve nada y cuando se recibe su respuesta no hay forma de saber que no hubo errores. Como te comenté antes, este tipo de códigos se controlan con un array ...

Comment: ... en el cual puedes poner algunas claves a verificar, que podrían ser: `error`, `success` y usarías esas claves cuando haya error o cuando no los haya, luevo verificarías si la respuesta tiene una de esas claves y así sabrás qué hacer. Se trata simplemente de dar coherencia al código, integrándolo a una lógica definida.

Comment: Supongo que el chico que hizo el tutorial debió hacerlo así porque pensó que seria más sencillo para principiantes. Cuando yo estudiaba javaScript también nos enseñaban a presentar los errores de esa manera. Aunque con un array si que queda todo más limpio. Cuando acabe el código, ya implementaré y cambiaré cosas para mejorarlo e ir aprendiendo al mismo tiempo. Lo de los arrays no se me habia ocurrido, pero me parece un buen modo de recoger los errores.

Comment: En teoría si los datos son correctos, queda registrado y se introducen en la base de datos y no muestra ningún mensaje, pero se puede mostrar uno de "El registro se ha realizado correctamente". Pero su ausencia no debería crear ningún tipo de error al código. Por otra parte, es difícil hacer las cosas correctamente cuando tratas de estudiar en unas condiciones que no son las mas óptimas. Pero tengo que tener una nociones de php (sin ser un experto) para un proyecto personal. Indiscutiblemente, cuanto mejor sepa hacer las cosas mejor.

Comment: @jbort revisa [este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/326184/29967). En él se usa un array llamado `$respuesta` donde se va poniendo en una clave `status` un `TRUE` cuando no hay errores  y un `FALSE`  cuando los hay. Luego se verifica la respuesta, mirando lo que hay en `status` y a partir de ahí se muestran los datos o se muestra un mensaje de error. Es un estilo de trabajar que puedes implementar sin demasiada dificultad en tu código. Generalmente en una aplicación los errores no se integran al contenido normal. O sea que en este caso una situación de error no iría integrada a un `li`

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano, me ha quedado bastante claro, lo implementare en mi código y trabajare con este método, me parece mucho más limpio. Gracias por tu esfuerzo y trabajo.